# Unset primary key for update ZfcBase

Tags: zend-framework2

I am using the ZfcBase to update a table, when I pass the entity and extract the raw data it gets the entity Id (which is the primary key), but I dont want to include the id for update, whats the appropriate way to exclude the entity id (primary key) so it does not get on the sql statement?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I did I just pass a plain array instead of the object.

```
    $entity = array('authorized' => $authorize);
    $where = array('id' => $id);
    $mapper->update($entity , $where);
```

this is the mapper

```
public function update($entity, $where = null, $tableName = null, Hydrator $hydrator = null)
{
    $hydrator = $hydrator ?: $this->getHydrator();

    if (!$where) {
        $where = array('order_id' => $entity->getId());
    }

    return parent::update($entity, $where, $this->getTableName(), $hydrator);
}
```

in the ZfcBase AbstractDbMapper there is a method that gets call on the update

```
$rowData = $this->entityToArray($entity, $hydrator);


protected function entityToArray($entity, HydratorInterface $hydrator = null)
{
    if (is_array($entity)) {
        return $entity; // cut down on duplicate code
    } elseif (is_object($entity)) {
        if (!$hydrator) {
            $hydrator = $this->getHydrator();
        }

        return $hydrator->extract($entity);
    }
    throw new Exception\InvalidArgumentException('Entity passed to db mapper should be an array or object.');
}
```

As you can see this method accepts either and object or an array. I just sent a plain array.